# Null Object Ref creating index after updating to v 0.11.1.0

Tags: nest

Ive just updated my nuget of Nest to the latest version 0.11.1.0 from 0.9.20.6 and I now get a null object ref creating the index. My code is unchanged, but maybe it was never right. I've also updated Json.Net to v 5.0.6.2 and the call stack indicated that the JsonSerializer is where its failing.

The call stack is thus:

```
at Nest.Resolvers.Converters.IndexSettingsConverter.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(RootObjectMapping m) in c:\Work\NEST\src\Nest\Resolvers\Converters\IndexSettingsConverter.cs:line 113
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionaryTSource,TKey,TElement
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionaryTSource,TKey
at Nest.Resolvers.Converters.IndexSettingsConverter.WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer) in c:\Work\NEST\src\Nest\Resolvers\Converters\IndexSettingsConverter.cs:line 112
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeConvertable(JsonWriter writer, JsonConverter converter, Object value, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Type type, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
at Nest.ElasticClient.Serialize(Object object) in c:\Work\NEST\src\Nest\ElasticClient-Statics.cs:line 53
at Nest.ElasticClient.CreateIndex(String index, IndexSettings settings) in c:\Work\NEST\src\Nest\ElasticClient-CreateIndex.cs:line 18
...
```

This is failing because a field mapping has a null TypeNameMarker property (see the Nest source for the first line in the trace above).

I create the field maps manually (from some XML definitions in the app) thus:

```
new StringMapping() { Name = fieldname, Index = idx, Store = field.Store };
```

Does anyone know why this has changed?

## UPDATE

Here's the full code I use to create the map.  You can see I've commented out the TypeNameMarker as this is a new property for 0.11.

```
    IElasticType createFieldMap(Field field, bool notAnalyzed = false, string fieldname = null)
    {
        IElasticType att = null;

        var idx = notAnalyzed ? FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed : (FieldIndexOption?)Enum.Parse(typeof(FieldIndexOption), field.Index);
        var nsidx = notAnalyzed ? NonStringIndexOption.not_analyzed : (NonStringIndexOption?)Enum.Parse(typeof(NonStringIndexOption), field.Index);
        var ft = (FieldType)Enum.Parse(typeof(FieldType), field.Type);

        fieldname = fieldname ?? field.Name;

        switch (ft)
        {
            case FieldType.string_type:
                att = new StringMapping()
                {
                    Name = fieldname,
                    Index = idx,
                    Store = field.Store,
                    //TypeNameMarker = "string"
                };
                if (field.CodeField)
                {
                    (att as StringMapping).SearchAnalyzer = "keyword";
                    (att as StringMapping).IndexAnalyzer = "keyword";
                }
                else
                {
                    (att as StringMapping).SearchAnalyzer = "simple";
                    (att as StringMapping).IndexAnalyzer = "simple";
                }
                break;
            case FieldType.binary:
                att = new BinaryMapping()
                {
                    Name = fieldname,
                    //TypeNameMarker = "binary"
                };
                break;
            case FieldType.boolean_type:
                att = new BooleanMapping()
                {
                    Name = fieldname,
                    Index = nsidx,
                    Store = field.Store,
                    //TypeNameMarker = "boolean"
                };
                break;
            case FieldType.date_type:
                att = new DateMapping()
                {
                    Name = fieldname,
                    Index = nsidx,
                    Store = field.Store,
                    //TypeNameMarker = "date"
                };
                break;
            case FieldType.double_type:
            case FieldType.float_type:
            case FieldType.integer_type:
            case FieldType.long_type:
                att = new NumberMapping()
                {
                    Name = fieldname,
                    Index = nsidx,
                    Store = field.Store,
                    //TypeNameMarker = "number"
                };
                break;
        }
        return att;
    }
```

Each field is added to the rootmap.

```
var props = new Dictionary<string, IElasticType>();

foreach (var field in doc.IndexMap.Fields)
{
    if (!field.Sortable)
    {
        props.Add(field.Name, createFieldMap(field));
    }
    else
    {
        var mfm = new MultiFieldMapping();
        mfm.Name = field.Name;

        mfm.Fields.Add(field.Name, (IElasticCoreType)createFieldMap(field));
        mfm.Fields.Add("sort", (IElasticCoreType)createFieldMap(field, true, "sort"));

        props.Add(field.Name, mfm);
    }
  }
  rootMap.Properties = props;
```

There is a large xml file that contains the list of fields to include in the index.  The actual records are returned from SQL and this same XML file has the queries to execute and some change tracking info (using rowversions).

Comment: I've reverted to 0.90.20.6 and it works fine.

Comment: Hey Jonesie I'd love to fix this! can you post some more code? How does your full map code look like and what exactly is the POCO you use?

Comment: Thanks!  See update above. Oh, and the POCO's are dynamic objects returned by Dapper from SQL queries.

Comment: what i notice is that you use TypeNameMarker to denote the type of field but it should be used to specifuy the name of the field

Comment: ... But specifying Name should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to catch the bug in a [failing unit test](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest.Tests.Integration/Reproduce/Reproduce319Tests.cs)

What happened was that if you use the `.MapFluent()` method it makes sure to set the TypeNameMarker for you behind the scenes. If you manually new your mapping objects the code at `IndexSettingsConverter.cs:line 113` did not fall back gracefully on `.Name`

this is now fixed and we it throws a better exception in case both `.Name` and `.TypeNameMarker` are missing.